# NSArray sort against another NSArray of strings

Tags: ios, sorting, nsstring, nsarray

I feel like this is simple but I just can't wrap my head around it. I have an array of days of the week that a user can select against:

```
NSArray * daysOfTheWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sunday", @"monday", @"tuesday", @"wednesday", @"thursday", @"friday", @"saturday", nil];
```

I as the toggle the days on and off, I'd like to sort their NSArray fo selected days against the `dayOfTheWeek` NSArray. So if a user has:

```
NSArray * userDays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"thursday", @"monday", @"friday"];
```

I want to sort this so that its monday, thursday, friday.

I'd seem some of the similar questions posted but none were clear enough for me to know how I could apply them to this. Could be my lack of sleep :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSArray *sortedUserDays = [userDays sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [@([daysOfTheWeek indexOfObject:a]) compare:@([daysOfTheWeek indexOfObject:b])];
}];
```

**Edit:** This sorts the array using a block as a comparator.

To compare two elements of the `userDays` array it first searches their positions in the template array `daysOfTheWeek`: `[daysOfTheWeek indexOfObject:a]`

It then wraps the positions into NSNumbers: `@(index)`.

Next it calls `compare:` on the wrapped indices. That's just a lazy way of returning an `NSComparisonResult` for the two `NSUInteger` positions.

Comment: Thanks very much this seems to do the trick. Would you or someone else please explain a bit about whats happening?

Answer (score 4):

Another way you could do this is by simply filtering your days of the week with the users options.

```
NSArray *sortedUserDays = [daysOfTheWeek filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF in (%@)", userDays]];
```